# An object should not call itself?

Tags: oop, object, call

I was going through some sequence diagram reference material and came across this quote from the web page [UML basics](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html)

> A purist would argue that an object should never send a message to itself. However, modeling an object sending a message to itself can be useful in some cases.

Can someone elaborate on this? Who are these purists?

Comment: I think in oop an object contains data and the methods appropriate to act on that data. Making a call to itself would therefor seam pointless in most cases because the object could just call the function instead. (CAUTION: I am not an authority on oop, just my understanding of it)

Comment: @Chris I thought an object calling a function on itself *is* modeled as a message to self? How else would you show it in a sequence diagram?

Comment: @ChrisDrew That's a fair point, I am not too familiar with the UML specifications and what they say about this, however one might argue that this is part of the "abstraction" provided by oop. It could be argued, that whatever a call to the object from "outside" causes the object to do only should be shown if it involves interacting with a different object. For instance in the linked document it would be important to show if `determineAvailableReports` would be a call to say a data-base object but not if the object can give them on its own.